# How do you create a UIAlertView based on the text in a UITextField?

Tags: ios6, uitextfield, uialertview, xcode4.5

I want to enter text into a text field and based on the text (if it says "No") I want the alertview to pop up. I've created a UITextField in interface builder and attached it to the UITextField delegate in the files owner so that's all taken care of. But when I enter text into the text field, specifically no, and click out of the textfield or remove the keyboard, no alertview pops up. I have created an entire method for this within the viewcontroller.m file. Here is the code for that method.

-(void)engageAlert {

```
 if (myTextField.text == @"No") {
      theAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notice" message:@"MyMessageHere"
      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
      [theAlertView show];
 }
```

}

Am I missing something here? Nothing happens when I type No into the textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the culprit will be the line

```
myTextField.text == @"No"
```

Since you're comparing two pointers which will never match.

@"No" = 0x12341234 or whatever address for the static address of the NSString (@"" can be thought of as short hand for the compiler creating the NSString object)

What you will want is something like

```
if( [myTextField.text isEqualToString:@"No"])
```

Also check you're not going to leak memory with theAlertView as I can't see where you're freeing that in the snippet.

Comment: This makes sense, I changed my if statement to what you have there but I'm still getting no response. Is there a way to check the string when exiting the interface of the textfield? As far as leaking memory goes I honestly have no idea. What you see there for my code is it for the uialertview

Comment: When are you calling engageAlert?

Comment: I have the method called right after viewDidLoad. I can't think of anywhere else to call the method. Idealy I would want to call it when the user exits the interface of the textfield but I'm usure how to do this.

Comment: It works just fine if I call the method after calling an IBAction button. I'd like to do this without a button if possible. Like check the status of the textfield strings when exiting the interface